# BEGIN ... END and DECLARE in MEMSQL 6 beta

Tags: singlestore

In databses like SQL Server or Hana it is possible to put statements in block using

```
 BEGIN
  DECLARE start TIMESTAMP;
  DECLARE end TIMESTAMP;

  start = now();
  select some_udf(X_ID) from X;
  end = now();

  select DATEDIFF(start, end);
END;
```

How is this possible in MEMSQL? If I understood it correctly BEGIN ... END can only be used with procedures or functions?!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write code like that in a stored procedure: http://docs.memsql.com/v6.0-beta/docs/create-procedure.

Comment: I already tested this and it gave me 'SELECT inside stored procedure as statement' is not supported.